# ı cant remove standard date sql

Tags: sql

I used union all to show the number of rows. I left the other fields blank. But the date fields come as standard dates. can you help me how can i remove it

[image]

I want the date fields to be blank on the first line

Comment: What do you mean by "standard date"?

Comment: Date from first row in data joined field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is because SQL is a strongly typed language and an empty string isn't a valid value for non-string types. There is however a non-value that *is* compatible with every type - `null`.

Comment: That's what you get when you specify an invalid date, as you have done here.  Perhaps you should be using NULL instead of an empty string.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Hope that the email and phone numbers don't belong to some real individuals ! Btw, as a side note : You'd better preferring text data rather than images, along with tagging the DBMS that you're using as well ...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

UNION operator generally (for most dbms products) get their data-types from the first query. If your first query has a `date` type for a column, the second query for the respective column should also return a date, or else it would be implicitly converted to date (you will get an error if it can't be converted). If you have supplied blank for that column, your dbms can implicitly convert it to 1900-01-01... One way to show blank there (blank is not a date) is to format (convert) the dates to varchar/char in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `Data Joined` in the part after `union all` to varchar. What is hapening here - sql tries to convert empty string '' to date and that's result - '1900 ...' . Try this :

```
CONVERT(varchar, [Data Joined], 101)
```